# Problem with rms and dB values of discrete samples

Tags: c, audio, raspberry-pi, sampling, pcm

I'm trying to sample pcm-data via the ALSA-project on my RaspberryPi 4 in c. Recording things works like a charm, but tampering with the samples themselves leaves me confused, especially since i already did the same on a different project (ESP32).

Consider "buffer" as an array of varying size per session (ALSA allocates differently every time) containing 32bit 44100Hz discrete audio samples stored as 8 bit values (int32_t cast needed). In order to get the dBFS value of a time stretch as big as one buffer i thought to square every sample, add them together, divide by the number of samples, get the sqrt, divide by the INT32_MAX value and pull the log10 from that, which is finally multiplied by 20. A standard rms and then dBFS calculation:

```
uint32_t sum = 0;
int32_t* samples = (int32_t*)buffer;
for(int i = 0; i < (size / (BIT_DEPTH/8)); i ++){

    sum += (uint32_t)pow(samples[i], 2);
}
double rms = sqrt(sum / (size / (BIT_DEPTH/8)));
int32_t decibel = (int32_t)(20 * log10(rms / INT32_MAX));
fprintf(stderr, "sum = %d\n", sum);
fprintf(stderr, "rms = %d\n", rms);
fprintf(stderr, "%d dBFS\n", decibel);
```

But instead of reasonable values for a somewhat quiet room (open window) or a speaker right next to the mics I get non-changing really quiet values of around -134 dBFS. Yes, the gain is low, so -134 could be possible but what I understand even less is what happens when I print out variables sum and rms:

```
buffersize: 262144
sum = -61773
rms = -262146
-138 dBFS
```

How could they ever be negative? This is probably a classic c-issue which I can't see at the moment.

Again: writing the samples to a file results in a high quality but low gain wav-file (header needed). Any help? thanks.

Comment: Could your RPi and esp32 have different endianness? Or, how the 32 bit data is sampled/ordered from the device?

Comment: In the future when asking for debugging help, provide a [mre] in the question.

Comment: Just a small hint: When calculating dB_rms you can omit the square root of the sum of squares and multiply by 10 instead of 20. As a matter of fact doing it that way is a far better representation of what dB means in relation to the underlying physics.

Comment: Well, to reproduce this I'd need to include the whole ALSA pcm-init and you'd need two i2s-MEMS-mics ready to go. That's why I thought I should keep it short and focus on the problematic area, which is solely dependant on math and c-standards, judging by the answer

Answer (score 1):

`sum` is a `uint32_t`, but you are printing it with `%d`, which is for `int`. The resulting behavior is not defined by the C standard. A common result is for values with the high bit set to be printed as negative numbers, but other behaviors are possible too. A correct conversion specification for `unsigned int` is `%u`, but, for `uint32_t`, you should include `<inttypes.h>` and use `fprintf(stderr, "%" PRIu32 "\n", sum);`.

Additionally, the squares and the summation may exceed what can be represented in a `uint32_t`, resulting in wrapping modulo 2<sup>32</sup>.

`rms` is a `double`, but you are also printing it with `%d`, which is very wrong. Use `%g`, `%f`, or `%e`, or some other conversion for `double`, possibly with various modifiers to select formatting options.

With the `int32_t` `decibel`, `%d` might work in some C implementations, but a proper method is `fprintf(stderr, "%" PRId32 " dBFS\n", decibel);`.

Your compiler should have warned you of at least the `double` format issue. Pay attention to compiler warnings and fix the problems they report. Preferably, escalate compiler warnings to errors with the `-Werror` switch to GCC and Clang or the `/WX` switch to MSVC.

The line `int32_t* samples = (int32_t*)buffer;` may result in prohibited aliasing. Be very sure that the memory for `buffer` is probably defined to allow it to be aliased as `int32_t`. If it is not, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, and alternative techniques of accessing the buffer should be used, such as copying the data into an `int32_t` object one at a time or into an array of `int32_t`.

Do not use `pow` to compute squares as it is wasteful (and introduces inaccuracies when other types are involved). For your types, use `static inline uint32_t square(int32_t x) { return x*x; }` and call it as `square(samples[i])`. If overflow is occurring, consider using `int64_t` when computing the square and `uint64_t` for the sum.